# Copy list of all Protected folders in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, windows-11

I recently started using the Widows `Protected folders` feature (also known as `Controlled folder access`).

I can see all the folders that I've added as Protected folders in the Windows security UI.
But is there a way I can get the complete list so that I can copy-paste it somewhere else?

Comment: Check this [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a09aca42-f2f3-43ff-b8be-12bd8af7c123/export-all-the-controlled-folder-access-settings-with-allowed-apps-etc) post out and if it works, I'll create an answer from it

Comment: Thanks, that post has command(s) for getting the list of applications having access to the controlled folders, but not for getting the list of controlled folders itself, unless I'm missing something. The list of applications is also useful otherwise though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open PowerShell and run the following command. This should give you a list of the folders you have declared as controlled folder access.

```
Get-MpPreference | Select ControlledFolderAccessProtectedFolders
```

Comment: We always appreciate the input from new contributors, but do you have a source and/or reference for your answer?

Comment: Thanks, I just had to add `-ExpandProperty` to get the expanded list. Accepting as answer.